# Cosine function completeness relations

Tags: fourier-analysis, dirac-delta

Does anyone how to prove the following completeness relations?
$$\delta(\theta-\theta')=\frac{1}{\pi}\sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}\cos(n\theta)\cos(n\theta')$$
Is there an analogous relation for $\sin(\theta)$ as well?

Comment: As stated, it's not true.  Note that the right side is invariant under $\theta \to -\theta$ and $\theta \to \theta + 2\pi$, the left is not.

Comment: Say we restrict $\theta$ and $\theta'$ to be from 0 to $\pi$.